# rust, bignums and windows

Tags: windows, rust, bignum

I've got rust 1.18.0 on windows 10 and I'd like to write something that uses bignums. The [rug](https://crates.io/crates/rug) library looks like a good choice, but a `cargo build` on a project using it fails because building gmp calls `ln -s` somewhere down the line.

- Is there a rust bignum library that can be compiled on windows out of the box?
- If not, are there instructions somewhere for using rug with a prebuilt libgmp?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/tspiteri/gmp-mpfr-sys#building-on-windows

Comment: I was hoping to avoid "install MSYS" if at all possible.

Comment: @Bristol I think that if you want to use some tools for system languages under windows, it is always good to have the GNU tools.

Comment: What kind of big numbers are you looking for? Does the `num` crate fulfill your needs? Note that we should not be asking recommendation questions.

Comment: I'll try with num.